# xml nodes() in tsql - matching parent nodes with child node attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I am trying to query following xml structure:

```
<effect><![CDATA[<p>some text</p>]]>
  <product code="4298271" />
  <product code="4298273" />
  <product code="4298274" />
  <product code="4298275" />
  <product code="4298276" />
</effect>
<effect><![CDATA[<p>some other text</p>]]>
  <product code="5298271" />
  <product code="5298273" />
  <product code="5298274" />
  <product code="5298275" />
  <product code="5298276" />
</effect>
```

I need to transform this data to a table like below:

```
Effect   ProductCode

some text       4298271
some text       4298273
some text       4298274
...
...
```

Is it even possible ? I can get the list of product rows which are under every effect parent but no idea how to match it with the effect header from which the text should be queried.

Let's say that effect is root node for simplifying.

Comment: That XML **isn't** valid - a XML document **must have** a single root element - not multiple....

Comment: The XML is not well-formed. Please share what you already tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the XML isn't really a valid document - you can still query it in T-SQL using XQuery - something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<effect><![CDATA[<p>some text</p>]]>
  <product code="4298271" />
  <product code="4298273" />
  <product code="4298274" />
  <product code="4298275" />
  <product code="4298276" />
</effect>
<effect><![CDATA[<p>some other text</p>]]>
  <product code="5298271" />
  <product code="5298273" />
  <product code="5298274" />
  <product code="5298275" />
  <product code="5298276" />
</effect>'

SELECT
    xc.value('(../text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    xc.value('(@code)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/effect/product') AS XT(XC)
```

This produces an output:

[image]

Adjust as needed ....

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it's working fine. The only issue I have is with performance because I'm querying over 50k product codes. I as unaware that it is possible to get this solution using [1] , as I tried previously to join the parent node from the child node and hen I used [1] in parent node I only got the first parent node in whole xml matched to every child.

Comment: @h4t3R: if you have **that many** product codes - you should really put those into a proper relational table, and not store them deep inside a convoluted XML structure....

Comment: Sure, but first I need to read them from xml and this product codes appear under more nodes than only "effects" and each should be queried separately and then merged in the database.